# MYSQL Inner Join , group by and order by using

Tags: mysql

I want merge datas from mysql database with sql reqeust

this messages.tbl

```
id : 1
sender : ali
responder : aishe
message : hi,how are you aishe
xid : md5($sender.$responder)--for using group by xid
id : 1
sender : ali
responder : aishe
message : answer me aishe plase
xid : md5($sender.$responder)--for using group by xid
```

and this  members.tbl

```
id : 1
nickname  : ali
img : ali.jpg
```

second record in members.tbl

```
id:2
nickname : aishe
img : aishe.jpg
```

i want list group by xid and in messages lastest showing

my english so poor sorry . 
please help me guys

so ali sent 50 posts messages
and john post 20 messages
and mike 5 messages

i want writen to page
like  : 
 Ali's lastest message and ali's picture
 John's lastest message and his picture
 Mike's lastest message and his picture

order by lastest messages and group by xid(like : 44asd32asd12)

understanding?

Comment: No need to apologise for your English, but what may help is if you provided example data (in table form) and then post what results you would like from your example data.

Comment: what relations you have maintained b/w tables

Comment: ali says : how areu 
john :    "good luck"
mike : "see you"

like this lastest message come first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to show the messages sent by every user, or you want to show the last message sent by each user.

If you want to show the messages for every user, you can use this query:

```
select 
    members.*, -- Put the fields you want from table members (e.g. members.id, ...)
    messages.* -- Put the fields you want from table messages (e.g. messages.message, ...)
from 
    members
    inner join messages on members.nickname = messages.sender;
```

If you want the last message sent by every user, you can use a subquery to filter the data:

```
select
    members.*,
    messages.*
from
    members
    inner join messages on members.nickname = messages.sender
    inner join (
        select sender, max(id) as maxId
        from messages
        group by sender
    ) as a on messages.id = a.maxId;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks your interting but i am taking this error "Unknown column 'nickname' in 'field list'"

Comment: @baraka can you add me in skype ? i must need help

Comment: @CumhurYrdkl what do you need, specifically? what is your desired output?

Comment: giving error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.nickname = mesajlar.gonderici inner join ( select gonderici, max(id' at line 6

Comment: sender : gonderici, messages : mesajlar

Comment: @CumhurYrdkl Ok, I've corrected the second error... try it now. I recommend you look for a good sql tutorial (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp may be a good place to start) or a good book on databases